# Using .Shared project in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, win-universal-app

I have an universal app, which contains shared project between Win8\Phone project. And i have some winRT component(project for background task), so how i can link from background task's project to shared project in universal app?

Answer (score 0):

The [Shared Project Reference Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/315c13a7-2787-4f57-bdf7-adae6ed54450) extension will enable this functionality for Visual Studio 2013.  Once that extension is installed, you can browse and add shared projects as you would add any other reference to a project.

There are two caveats to be mindful of:

1. The extension adds an  entry into your project file (.csproj).  That  entry has a condition on it that only adds it if the shared project file path exists.  While perhaps seeming innocuous, this can lead to a bunch of orphaned entries in your project file if you rename, move, refactor things, or, if there is an issue with the shared project on disk such as changing its location, you only find out about it at compile time, not when the project is loaded.
2. As noted in comments for the extension, the extension causes performance issues with Visual Studio 2013 when you have a large number of projects, especially during startup/shutdown of Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2015 has built-in support for shared projects, and provides a much richer set of functionality baked into the IDE:

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/